# "incomplete type" on using C++ units units::compose

Tags: c++, templates, units-of-measurement

I'm using the C++ Units library by Calum Grant http://calumgrant.net/units/ to manage values representing lengths or speeds.

Now I need a unit not specified by this library, and that is feet per minute. According to http://calumgrant.net/units/units.html you can make new units like this:

`typedef units::compose< units::units::m, units::pow<units::units::s, -1> > meters_per_second;`

but this example doesn't work. If I specify

```
typedef units::compose< units::units::foot, units::pow<units::units::minute, -1> > 
feet_per_minute;
feet_per_minute vertical_speed(12);
```

I get the following compile error (using gcc 4.2.1 on Mac)

```
error: variable 'feet_per_minute vertical_speed' has initializer but incomplete type
```

and this error when compiling with clang 3

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'units::compose<units::scale<units::scale<units::scale<units::units::m, 100, 1>, 100, 254>, 1, 12>, units::pow<units::scale<units::units::s, 1, 60>, -1, 1> >'
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just found the problem. There exist "units" and there exist "values" of those unit. So the correct definition is as follows:

```
namespace units {

namespace units {
     typedef compose< foot, pow<minute, -1> > fpm;
}

namespace values {
    typedef value<double, units::fpm> fpm;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try feet per second. See if that works then repost